# Spring WS - Use PayloadValidatingInterceptor to validate a single SOAP Web Service

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-ws

I have a project that exposes several SOAP endpoints. I want to use PayloadValiditatingInterceptor provided by Spring WS to validate only a particular end-point. However, my current implementation is applying validation to each and every SOAP endpoint.

The source code is as follows:

```
@Bean(name = "requestMessage")
public SimpleXsdSchema requestMessage()
{
    return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("com/schemas/2_0/requestMessage.xsd"));
}

@Override
public void addInterceptors(List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors)
{
    PayloadValidatingInterceptor validatingInterceptor = new PayloadValidatingInterceptor();
    validatingInterceptor.setValidateRequest(true);
    validatingInterceptor.setXsdSchema(requestMessage());
    interceptors.add(validatingInterceptor);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working by removing the addInterceptors method and adding the following lines in Configuration class.

```
public class SoapConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Bean
    PayloadValidatingInterceptor myEndpointValidatingInterceptor() {
    PayloadValidatingInterceptor interceptor = new 
    PayloadValidatingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setValidateRequest(true);
    interceptor.setXsdSchema(requestMessage());
    return interceptor;
    }

    @Bean
    PayloadRootSmartSoapEndpointInterceptor myEndpointValidator() {
        return new    
    PayloadRootSmartSoapEndpointInterceptor(myEndpointValidatingInterceptor(), 
    RequestEndPoint.NAMESPACE, RequestEndPoint.REQUEST_LOCAL_PART);
    }
}
```